# Symfony 3 bind data to form from PUT request

Tags: php, symfony, angular

I have a small question, how should I bind PUT request in symfony to form, if `Request` is empty.

Even if I get access to data with

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

I have got incorrect structure to bind data and `$form->handleRequest` will not work as expected. There is no form name and hierarchy is not observed. 
I get an object of post from angular interface.
[image]

<strike>Or should i bind data directly to entity.</strike>

Comment: Someone have any ideas??

Comment: Hello, what you mean by "getting incorrect structure" ? You mean you don't have the data from the submitted form ? If it's that, check that the form have the attribut "_method" with value "PUT"